# limit spaces to only one in text - c

Tags: c, getchar

I'm reading through K&R and the question is to: write a program to copy its input to its output, replacing each string of one or more blanks by a single blank. In my mind I think I know what I need to do, set up a boolean to know when I am in a space or not. I've attempted it and did not succeed. I've found this code and it works, I am struggling to figure out what stops the space from being written. I think I may have it but I need clarification.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int c;
  int inspace;

  inspace = 0;
  while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
  {
    if(c == ' ')
    {
      if(inspace == 0)
      {
        inspace = 1;
        putchar(c);
      }
    }

    /* We haven't met 'else' yet, so we have to be a little clumsy */
    if(c != ' ')
    {
      inspace = 0;
      putchar(c);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I have created a text file to work on, the text reads:

```
so this    is where    you have been
```

After the 's' on 'this' the state changes to 1 because we are in a space. The space gets written and it reads the next space. So now we enter:

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
      {
        if(c == ' ')
        {
          if(inspace == 0)
          {
            inspace = 1;
            putchar(c);
          }
```

But inspace is not 0, it is 1. So what happens? Does the code skip to return 0;, not writing anything and just continues the while loop? return 0; is outside of the loop but this is the only way I can see that a value is not returned.

Comment: It skip to `if (c != ' ')` which it skips too, continuing to loop. You can see that `putchar(c)` (echoing the input) is only done when not space (second if) or when space (first if) and inspace = 0. Where `inspace` means "after having read a space before".

Comment: It is ridiculous to say "we have not met `else` yet"; damn well introduce `else` at this point to prevent such ludicrous circumlocutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this point:

```
if(c == ' ')
{
   if(inspace == 0) // <-- here
```

If inspace is equal to 1, it will not execute the if body, it will jump to:

```
if(c != ' ') {
```

And as long as c == ' ' above will be false, so it will skip the if body and jump to:

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
```

And this will continue until the end of the file or until `(c != ' ')` evaluates to true. When c is non-space:

```
 if(c != ' ')
 {
   inspace = 0;
   putchar(c);
```

inspace is zeroed, and character is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah in the case you mentioned, it does not write anything and continues in the while loop and fetches the next character. If the next character is again space then it will do the same thing i.e go to next iteration without printing. Whenever it will find first non-space it will set inspace to 0 and start printing.

While loop will terminate whenever getchar will fetch EOF. Then program will return 0.

Answer (score 0):

If a condition in an if-statement is not true, the following expression is not executed. This means that everything inside the corresponding brackets is skipped and the execution resumes 'after' the closing bracket.

As the following if-statement is also false, nothing is done inside this iteration of the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

When inspace is 1 and c is ' ' the expression:

```
inspace == 0
```

evaluates to 0 and the code

```
inspace = 1;
putchar(c);
```

does not get executed.

The program will then go to the next iteration of the while loop if it can, but it won't return 0 until the while loop has ended.

You can simplify the while loop to this code:

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
  if(c == ' ')
  {
    if(inspace == 0)
    {
      inspace = 1;
      putchar(c);
    }
  } else
  {
    inspace = 0;
    putchar(c);
  }
}
```